# mediaplayer starts a new instance when i return to the app

Tags: java, android, media, audio-streaming, internet-radio

Im making a simple radio streaming app. Everything works great but having a few buggy issues.

When i press the home screen of my device i want the radio to carry on playing. which it does, But as soon as i go to my app history and re-open the app. It starts a new session. this make for a very Un-Pleasurble piece of music lol.

The app is very simple in the way it works i have a media player and a media controller which is attached to a surfaceView in my xml.

Can some one please tell me the correct way to fix this issue as this is the first time making an app that contains a live stream.

Thanks as always guys

my code for the media player and controller

```
public class radiostation extends AppCompatActivity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback, MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener,
    MediaController.MediaPlayerControl {

private SurfaceView surfaceView;
private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

private MediaController mediaController;
private Handler handler = new Handler();

String videoSource =
        "my radio station source address";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_radiostation);

    surfaceView = (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.surface);
    surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
    surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);

    surfaceView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if(mediaController != null){
                mediaController.show();
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {

    Toast.makeText(radiostation.this,
            "Media Controls active lets mash it up", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mediaPlayer.setDisplay(surfaceHolder);
    mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
    try {
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(videoSource);
        mediaPlayer.prepare();

        mediaController = new MediaController(this);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(radiostation.this,
                "Radio Station off Air or no internet connection!\n" + e.toString(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder,
                           int format, int width, int height) {

}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {

}

@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
    mediaPlayer.start();
    Toast.makeText(radiostation.this,
            "You are now connected ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    mediaController.setMediaPlayer(this);
    mediaController.setAnchorView(surfaceView);
    handler.post(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            mediaController.setEnabled(true);
            mediaController.show();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void start() {
    mediaPlayer.start();
}

@Override
public void pause() {
    mediaPlayer.pause();
}

@Override
public int getDuration() {
    return mediaPlayer.getDuration();
}

@Override
public int getCurrentPosition() {
    return mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
}

@Override
public void seekTo(int pos) {
    mediaPlayer.seekTo(pos);
}

@Override
public boolean isPlaying() {
    return mediaPlayer.isPlaying();
}

@Override
public int getBufferPercentage() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public boolean canPause() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean canSeekBackward() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean canSeekForward() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public int getAudioSessionId() {
    return mediaPlayer.getAudioSessionId();
}
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    mediaPlayer.stop();
    mediaPlayer.release();
    mediaPlayer=null;
    finish();
}
```

Comment: well ... the code you've posted clearly shows that .... wait...

Comment: post your code.

Comment: thanks @BhuvaneshBs ive just added my code

Comment: @Stultuske added

Comment: have you tried with checking for a current instance before intitiating a new one?

Comment: Can you send the complete class so that we can see what functions are called when in its lifecycle?

Comment: added @Mehmed thanks for your help so far